# Vue route params, параметр из url заменяется на %2F

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Кому-нибудь когда-нибудь встречалось такое при работе с vue.js, что кусочек динамического url заменяется на "%2F"?

Есть схема роута:

```
path: '/:platform/login'
```

Таким образом, при вводе url "http://localhost:8080/test/login" test становится параметром $route.params.platform = 'test'.

В редких непонятных случаях, которые мне не удается воспроизвести, при вводе в адресную строку "http://localhost:8080/test/login" может замениться на "http://localhost:8080/%2F/login".

Никакими насильными действиями вроде написать '/' вместо 'test' в адресную строку или в хуке router.beforeEach(to, from, next) подменить параметр platform на '/' это не воспроизводится.
Происходит эта замена как будто до того, как отрабатывает хук router.beforeEach.

Ломаю голову, что это.

Версии:

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что в `:platform` может присутствовать только один символ `/`. А поскольку он как параметр url является недопустимым, браузер кодирует `encodeURIComponent('/') -> %2F`, а vue это не учитывает. Если ожидаете `/`, то при получении параметра обязательно декодируйте этот параметр и получите исходное значение: `decodeURIComponent('%2F') -> /`

Comment: попробую делать какую то обработку ошибки в хуке router.beforeEach() по условию if (to.params.platform === '/') редирект куда нибудь

Comment: Еще один вариант возникновения `/` это передача в `:platform` пустрой строки, а браузер (или сервер приложений при обновлении страницы) 2 рядом стоящих слеша преобразует `%2F`. Нет возможности воспроизвести, так бы сказал точнее.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но сама причина остается неясной, почему при вводе в адресную строку это произошло, то есть ввел какой то конкретный url, и тут из него пропадает кусок, который на месте :platform и подменяется на пустоту, то есть на %2F этот (